# 503 valid RCPT command must precede DATA

Tags: postfix, email, ubuntu

При отправке письма с помощью Postfix на mail.ru приходит ответное письмо с сообщением об ошибке вида:

```
Final-Recipient: rfc822; ...
Original-Recipient: rfc822;...
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; mxs.mail.ru
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 503 Valid RCPT command must precede DATA
```

В чем проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: Проверьте обратную запись DNS, и MX запись вашего домена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На mail.ru это может быть в случае, когда MX запись напрямую указывает на ip сервера, то есть

```
example.com     MX    5    1.2.3.4
```

вместо

```
example.com     MX    5    mail.example.com.
mail            A          1.2.3.4
```